# Windows phone minimal commandbar ellipsis interfering with my controls

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

If I try to hit the 'clear' button on my filter TextBox, the command bar thinks I'm trying to hit the ellipsis and opens, without letting my click through to the cross.

Is there anyway I can get around this?

[image]

Comment: Move it up a little? Other thing is you could increase the touch overhang (padding) of your button, but I think the appbar is always on top.

Comment: @KaiBrummund, I ended up just reducing the width on the textbox so that the x was moved left out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationBar is a system control where we can't do much. We can change colors, opacity and that's all. There is no way to modify this behavior.

You have to consider changes in your design. For me as a user and graphics designer it's really strange that your search box is on the bottom. It's natural to put it on the top. It's on the top everywhere in Windows Phone, so I suggest you to be consistent with the OS.

Comment: So the only solution is to move your TextBox up... ;)

Comment: I would also recommend moving the filter textbox to the top of the page. But if you really have to have it in the bottom, you can add the textbox in a Grid or StackPanel and adjust the padding or  bottom margin.This will only mask the real design issue.